# Linked server query slow, statistics taking a long time to return

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, columnstore

We have a 1.5tb clustered columnstore table, 900 partitions, on SQL Server 2016.

We created a linked server on a 2012 box, pointing at this server.

Doing a simple "select fielda, fieldb, fieldc from servera.databasea.dbo.tablea where partition_field = b and otherfield = c" takes 63 seconds.

I have sysadmin on both so I have the right to stats, but when I run a query sp_whoisactive shows that it's running `dbcc show_statistics(@qtbl, @statname) with stat_header join density_vector` for (as far as we can see) exactly 60 seconds before it changes to doing a query, at which point it finishes in 3 seconds.

So every linked server query takes at least 60 seconds. I've tried building the linked server using "SQL Server" and the Microsoft OLE Provider for SQL Server, and both do the same thing.  Is there any way to fix this behavior? Yes, we're moving off of 2012 in the next couple of months, but we have some pressing data needs before then. Our fallback is to copy the data ranges we need, but that could get ugly.

The reason for the linked server (as opposed to openquery) is to minimize the amount of code changes we need to make - if we can just point a view at that table, then no other code needs to be changed.

Collation Compatible is set to true, Data Access set to true, RPC & RPC Out are set to true.

Thanks.

Comment: Does `OPENQUERY` perform better? If it does, that might imply that the *entire* table is being sent over from the linked server, and then parsed by the instance you are connected to.

Comment: @larnu using openrowset from that server to the other server comes back in 3 seconds.  When the query runs the 2012 box says it's running the query, and the 2016 server says it's running the show_statistics.

Comment: And I just checked, openquery comes back in 3 seconds also.

Comment: Does the plan show that all 900 partitions are scanned? I wonder if the additional filter is preventing partition elimination. (Also I might consider a synonym instead of a view.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Running that now.  The estimated didn't give me any details but also took 1 minute.

Comment: The execution plan from the first server just shows remote query, nothing about partitions used. I didn't know you could do cross-server synonyms, trying that.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that plans hide everything behind that operator. :-( But that generating an estimated plan took a minute gives me a further hint that it is considering all 900 partitions, so unable to effectively use the filter on the partitioning key first. If `OPENQUERY()` didn't show this problem, I think it's _possible_ a synonym might bypass it as well. If not, then a view could certainly encapsulate an `OPENQUERY()` call instead.

Comment: @aaronbertrand Synonym to the linked server alias likewise takes 63 seconds.  I tried pointing the synonym at the server directly (no linked server), but it choked and wanted a linked server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand But I'd never tried using OPENROWSET/OPENQUERY for a view, and that'll work!  Submit that sucker as a solution and I'll accept it. THANK YOU!

Comment: Still curious why the heck it takes a full 60 seconds to get the statistics for that table - maybe it can't understand CCS because 2012 only supports CS?

Comment: I'd be curious if that DBCC command takes 60 seconds (a) when you run it manually using `linkedserver.database.sys.sp_executesql` and (b) when you run it locally on the other server. I don't think it could take _longer_ because of the version mismatch, but it might be happening simply _because of_ the mismatch.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I honestly had no idea that damn table had that many auto-created statistics on columns.  (column has 200+ fields).  It took a full 59 seconds to return using SP_EXECUTESQL, from the other server, and 63s running locally (and running on another server on the internal LAN also took 59 seconds) possibly since it returns 183 sets of data to SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the OPENQUERY version inside a view.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.whatever AS
  SELECT cols FROM OPENQUERY(...);
```

`OPENQUERY()` is essentially doing what you'd be doing if you:

- ran the query locally on the linked server
- used `servername.databasename.sys.sp_executesql @sql`

In those cases (which I know aren't viable options for you) I don't believe you'd be seeing the DBCC command running at all.